# MySql merge two date columns to one column by query

Tags: mysql

I have two date columns `from` and `to` i want to query like

```
SELECT cast(E.From as varchar(20)) + ' to ' + cast(E.To as varchar(20)) DateRange,  
       E.Reason, L.Title as LeaveType 
  FROM employeeleave E 
       LEFT JOIN listitems L ON E.LeaveTypeID = L.ListItemID
```

and make a new column `daterange`.

My query is not working.

How do i cast date values to varchar in mysql.

Comment: "My query is not working." What exactly does that mean?

Comment: my query isnot working in the way i want it to work. That is what is meant.

Comment: If we don't know how you want it to work, we can't help you make it work. Please provide your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need `concat`

```
SELECT concat(E.From,' to ',E.To) DateRange,
E.Reason,
L.Title as LeaveType 
from employeeleave E 
LEFT JOIN listitems L ON E.LeaveTypeID = L.ListItemID
```